# Setup debugging with Qt Creator bare metal project

Tags: debugging, qt-creator, bare-metal, segger-jlink

I'm completely new to embedded development and I've wanted to setup debugging from within Qt Creator. The project is a bare metal application and the project is a compile data base project. I have a J-Link debugger and device is a STM32L083VZ.

I have enabled the bare metal plugin and added a J-Link device like this:

[image: Device setting]

The settings for the kit looks like this:

[image]

In the run settings I've entered the full path to the generated elf-executable.

The button which should start a debug session is currently grayed out and when I hover over the button the message is "*Cannot run "Custom Executable"*":

[image]

Is there something I'm stil missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried debugging using "QT" but I think it is quite the same configuration steps I used in VS code.

You need to specify a GDB server: a software that communicates with the uC and provides the command interface to debug on QT IDE.

I've been using OpenOCD as GDB server in my applications and it works fine.

Here is a link to QT documentation explaining how to setup OpenOCD as GDB server:

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-baremetal.html#openocd

And here is the OpenOCD project website:
https://openocd.org/